# Is it possible to update the tabline every second?

Tags: redraw

I want a clock display in Vim. My statusline is pretty full, so I want to use the tabline. I use [taboo.vim](https://github.com/gcmt/taboo.vim) to control my tabline, and I replaced the useless `X` "button" with a clock display using the following line in my `.vimrc`:

```
" Put a clock in the top-right corner of the tabline
let g:taboo_close_tabs_label = "%{strftime('%a\ %e\ %b\ %I:%M:%S\ %p')}"
```

This creates a nice clock in the top-right corner:

[image: Clock on tabline in Vim]

The tabline updates when switching buffers, inserting text, etc. However, I want the clock to update every second. The closest I have come is with this:

```
" Update the clock whenever possible
autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI * silent redrawtabline
```

in conjunction with this (which I use for other purposes too):

```
set updatetime=100
```

Those two together cause the tabline to get redrawn every time I move the cursor (in addition to all the normal update times). But it's still not perfect because the clock still doesn't update when I'm not doing anything.

Is there a way to get my clock display to update every second (or every minute)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a timer, which you set up with [`timer_start()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#timer_start%28%29), in order to run a callback that will invoke [`redrawtabline`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Aredrawtabline) for you every second.

In your specific situation:

```
function! RedrawTabline(timerID)
  silent redrawtabline
endfunction
call timer_start(1000, 'RedrawTabline', {'repeat': -1})
```

Using `{'repeat': -1}` will make this timer repeat every second, forever.

You can store the result of the `timer_start()` call with the timer ID into a variable, if you intend to eventually call [`timer_stop()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#timer_stop%28%29) on it.

Comment: For the most part though, I wouldn't recommend adding a clock to your status or tab line in Vim, redrawing can be an expensive operation and Vim is not very well suitable to perform this kind of action.

Comment: I'm glad you clarified this is actually not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the warning. When I wrote it how you did, I got `Undefined function: RedrawTabline` when opening vim. So I tried changing the definition to `function! RedrawTabline()`, But then I got the message "E118: Too many arguments for function: RedrawTabline" every second. Finally, I tried defining it like `function! RedrawTabline(timerID)` to consume the first argument and that worked.

Comment: @nullromo Sorry for the oversight and thanks for the edit! Glad this was helpful!

Comment: @nullromo `function!` should not be necessary. I define most functions as `function F(…) abort`. The `!` is only needed for redefinitions.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks for causing me to read `:help function`. Some good stuff in there. I think `!` is not necessary here and `abort` is probably good to use almost always.

Comment: To be honest, I tend to use `function!` almost exclusively. In the old times you needed that in order to reload a script (not anymore), but still when I'm working in a temporary buffer and want to use `:@"` to source the yanked contents it's useful to have `function!` to redefine it as often as I'd like. Also, no big downsides from using `!`, it's unlikely I'll have name clashes and end up redefining something important (also, that protection mostly doesn't exist elsewhere anyways, like global variables.) In any case, both are probably just fine.